# New Column with Count Row Values -List Elements as dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Data Frame

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'StringMatch':['[mother]','[priest, mother,mother father]','[father, mother]']})
df
```

desired output

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'StringMatch':['[mother]','[priest, mother,mother father]','[father, mother]'], 'StringMatchCount':['{mother:1}', '{priest:1, mother:2, father:1}','{father:1, mother:1}']})
```

I tried the following:

```
df['StringMatchCount'] =df['StringMatch'].str.count(k)
df
```

Comment: the first df , are the words in lists?

Comment: Yap, thats is how the column looks. I need to count each element and input the result into a column.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from collections import Counter

#convert str repr of lists to lists if necessary
df['StringMatch'] = df['StringMatch'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',\s*|\s+')
#add Counter
df['StringMatchCount'] = df['StringMatch'].apply(Counter)
```

---

```
print (df)
                        StringMatch                         StringMatchCount
0                          [mother]                            {'mother': 1}
1  [priest, mother, mother, father]  {'priest': 1, 'mother': 2, 'father': 1}
2                  [father, mother]               {'father': 1, 'mother': 1}
```